# Can't install SMITE on ubuntu 14.04, Help?

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux, minecraft

I am fairly new to Ubuntu 14.04 (I am loving it so far) and I want to install some windows games on my PC. I managed to install Minecraft and LoL, but I can't install SMITE. I tried using the PlayOnLinux's function to install a non-listed program but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily possible to run windows games under Linux.

PlayOnLinux uses Wine to execute the windows binarys.

WineHQ has a database of various applications success rate for running under wine.

SMITE does not seem to work very well with a 'garbage' rating: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14324